# Unable to jump in Andengine with Box2D

Tags: andengine

I want to make player jumps following [this tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-12.html) but I can't. Please take a look into my code and help me to fix it. Here is my codes:

```
mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, 

SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH),false);
sapo = new Sapo(100,100,mVertexBufferObjectManager,mCamera,mPhysicsWorld) {
   @Override
   public void onDie() {}
   };
attachChild(sapo);
sapo.jump();
```

---

```
public abstract class Sapo extends AnimatedSprite {
private Body mBody;

public Sapo(float pX, float pY, VertexBufferObjectManager vbo, Camera camera, PhysicsWorld physicsWorld)
{
    super(pX, pY, ResourceManager.getInstance().mSapoTiledTextureRegion,vbo);
    createPhysics(camera, physicsWorld);
}
private void createPhysics(final Camera camera, PhysicsWorld physicsWorld)
{        
    mBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1f,1f,1f));
}

public abstract void onDie();
public void jump() {
    mBody.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(mBody.getLinearVelocity().x,-100));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I forgot to register the physic handler, like this:

```
myScence.registerUpdateHandler(mPhysicsWorld);
```